# Operator "new" in java, creating String with

Tags: java, string, oop, reference, jvm

What is the difference between creating Object, for example in my code, type Obj with operator "new" and Object type String?

```
public class Objs {
    int a;

    public Objs(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = new String("Hello");
        String str1 = str; // (str1 == str) == true
        str += ", world!!"; // after this (str1 == str) == false - Why?

        Objs o = new Objs(4);
        Objs o1 = o;        //(o == o1) == true
        o.a += 9;           // after this (o == o1) == true also
    }
}
```

Why after I'm changing value of "str", references "str" and "str1" become not equal, but if I'm doing the same with class Obj references stay equal?

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java. The assignment operator is putting a new string instance into the `str` variable, not modifying the original. Meanwhile, you never change the value referred to by the reference `o`. You simply update a property on that object instance.

Comment: you are not doing the same: adding something to an object (`str +=`) is not the same as adding something to a field of an object(`o.a +=`) {{your title is totally misleading - not related to `new`}}

Comment: Besides what @nbrooks said, important thing here is that: equals() compares the content and == checks the reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
str += ", world!!"
```

you're creating a new object with changed value (that's how `+` operator works for `String`s in java). Here:

```
o.a += 9;
```

you're modifying the field of the object, but it's still the same reference.

Comment: it means, that operator "+" creates a new string, and free memory of the previous?

Comment: Yes, but only if the other is not used

Comment: String is an immutable class so its instances can not be modified. += operator creates new String instance.

Comment: The "field of the object" (or, instance variable), not the "parameter on the object."

Comment: @GaripTipici yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 0):

Because a `String` type in  Java is immutable that means a string object can not be modified, instead, a new string object is created with the given expression.

`str += ", world!!";` // at this line, a new `str` object is created with given concatenation, hence str loses reference to the previous object and now points to the new one - that is the reason.